# Why is data is not printed on webpage, after being fetched from mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$retval = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM food WHERE pnrno='$pnrno'");
if ($retval) {
    echo "Your food complain has been successfully fetched";
    echo "<table border='1'>
        <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>PNR Number</th>
        <th>Food Complain Status</th>
        </tr>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval))
        {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['pnrno'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['complain_status'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        echo "\r\n";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $retval . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Code inside the while loop is not getting executed(I think so), "Your food complain has been successfully fetched" this message is getting printed, table is formed, but username, pnrno, and complain_status after being fetched from database is not printed on webpage. Why is it so, please help.

Comment: Try adding a var_dump($row) inside the while and see if it says anything interesting

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: You need to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton The default for `mysqli_fetch_array()` is `MYSQLI_BOTH` so `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` would be tidier, but not necessary

Comment: @RiggsFolly You're right, I've just not seen an instance where the other way is better

Comment: why don't you try to simply debug it first, what's the point to run to SOF with every tiniest scratch?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the data exists, and you're sending the query the correct parameter, the likely culprit is how you're using your `row` variable. Since you're not telling mysqli to fetch the array in an associative manner, it's defaulting to an index.

You need to change your fetch function to:

```
mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQLI_ASSOC)
```

Comment: Yeah, this or he could also use mysqli_fetch_assoc

Comment: The default is actually `MYSQLI_BOTH`

Answer (score 0):

```
$retval = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM food WHERE pnrno='$pnrno'");

if ($retval) {
```

Your `if` is going to execute if the query successfully executes.

However, a query for a non-existent row **will succeed**, with zero rows.

You'll want to check the number of rows returned by the query, and show an error if there aren't any matching ones.